# How to convert phrase to 1 word in php

Tags: php, string

I want PHP function that convert phrase to 1 word

example :

```
"i want gogo" ==> "i_want _gogo"
```

**Replace space with _**
How can i do it ?

Comment: You can use str_replace method as `str_replace(" ", "_", $<your_string_variable_name>) `

Answer (score 0):

This is very basic in PHP:

Reference: [str_replace](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_replace.asp)

```
<?php
echo str_replace(" ","_","i want gogo");
?>
```